# Is there a way to move your cpanel domain name to heroku?

Tags: cpanel

I bought a domain name together with a hosting server with cpanel. I'm moving to rails now, thus heroku. Is there a way to detach the domain name to my previous server to heroku via cpanel?

Answer (score 1):

If you are having custom name servers, Point that to the heroku IP from domain registrar end.

Before that make sure that website contents are placed correctly. Either take a backup from your current server and restore that at heroku.

> dig @heroku_ip domain.com

and make sure that its resolving correctly.

These are all you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at first you can edit the DNS information within cpanel to point your domain to your new site hosted at heroku. http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/SimpleDnsEditor

As a next step you can transfer the domain registration to heroku and cancel the old account.

Comment: I'll try and let you know.

Comment: can you elaborate further? It doesn't seem to work. DNS editor looks for an IP address which heroku avoids. thanks!